# Local testing for python 3 with datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, testing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Does anyone know how to simulate the datastore for local testing with python 3?

Java has the [local test utils](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/localunittesting)

python 2 has the [testbed module](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/localunittesting)

The documentation suggests using the datastore emulator, but even though it is working, I think it is not ideal to have the tests depending on an external process and it takes a lot of time to start

Answer (score 0):

A true unit test would not require an emulator/simulator of an external service. You should mock/monkeypatch/stub out any calls to datastore and make them return the expected response.

If what you're actually trying to do is a functional test or an integration test, using the [Cloud Datastore Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator) is the best choice.

Comment: I deleted the word unit.
But either way, I think linking tests that will be run by the CI with other processes is just more complexed than the solution for python 2 and Java.
Maybe I should rephrase my question  - does python 3 has any other option than datastore emulator?